# the discrete topology of an infinite set

Tags: general-topology

Hi I am very new to topology and was wondering how to solve the following problem :

Let X be an infinite set and τ a topology on X. If every infinite subset of X is in τ, prove that τ is the discrete topology.

I have trouble understanding why this would be true. It goes against my intuition of an infinite set and I don't quite understand how this topology would be discrete. As you could still pick any finite subset of X. Can anybody tell me why this true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Topology is really cool, I hope you'll like it!

Comment: @Jakobian thx! so far it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to show that for every $x\in X$, $\{x\}\in\tau$. Since $X$ is infinite, we can take an infinite countable subset $E\subset X$. Let $E=\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Then $A=\{x\}\cup\{a_{2n-1}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $B=\{x\}\cup\{a_{2n}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are infinite subsets of $X$, so $A,B\in\tau$. Since $\tau$ is a topology, we have $A\cap B=\{x\}\in\tau$, which completes the proof.

Comment: thx I ll aprove asap

Comment: Does the first step require some form of the axiom of choice? See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201324/countable-subset-of-a-uncountable-set

Comment: It does require. You start taking $a_1\in X$ arbitrarialy. Since $X$ is infinite, $X-\{a_1\}$ is not empty, so we can **choose** $a_2\in X-\{a_1\}$. We continue this process recursively.